# How do I extract religion fractions data from CountryData?

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data

In this code:

```
data = CountryData["UnitedStates", "ReligionsFractions"]
```

I need to extract all of the names of the various religions as a variable and the fraction as an associated value.

Comment: You can use `data = Association @@ 
   CountryData["UnitedStates", "ReligionsFractions"];` to create the association, then `Keys@data` to get the list of religions and `Values@data` to get the fractions.

Comment: How about `Evaluate[ToExpression /@ data[[All, 1, 2]]] = data[[All, 2]]`? This sets the religions as variables names, so `Protestant` evaluates to `0.513`. However, I don't like cluttering the namespace with lots of global variables, so `Association`s are better, as mentioned by @JasonB. A modified version is `AssociationThread[data[[All, 1, 2]] -> data[[All, 2]]]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
data = CountryData["UnitedStates", "ReligionsFractions"];
{#[[1, 2]], #[[2]]} & /@ data
```

> ```
> {{"Protestant", 0.513}, {"RomanCatholic", 0.239}, {"LatterDaySaints", 0.017}, 
>  {"Jewish", 0.017}, {"OtherChristian", 0.016}, {"Buddhist", 0.007}, 
>  {"Muslim", 0.006}, {"OtherNone", 0.186}}
> ```

or

```
Set @@@ ({Symbol[#[[1, 2]]], #[[2]]} & /@ data);
{Protestant, RomanCatholic, LatterDaySaints, Jewish, OtherChristian, Buddhist, 
 Muslim, OtherNone}
```

> `{0.513, 0.239, 0.017, 0.017, 0.016, 0.007, 0.006, 0.186}`

or

```
Association[#[[1, 2]] -> #[[2]] & /@ data]
```

> ```
> <|"Protestant" -> 0.513, "RomanCatholic" -> 0.239, "LatterDaySaints" -> 0.017, 
>   "Jewish" -> 0.017, "OtherChristian" -> 0.016, "Buddhist" -> .007, 
>   "Muslim" -> 0.006, "OtherNone" -> 0.186|>
> ```

Comment: One more, equivalent output to the last one, `data /. Entity[a_, b_] :> b // Association`